# OpenCV can't open webcamera in usb host

Tags: python, opencv

I have two difference web-cameras(*Trust 720HD* and *CANYON  CNR-WCAM 920HD*) connected to USB HUB TOTO hi-speed 4 that connected to my mac. When I am wanting to run this code with *Trust 720HD*

```
import cv2

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = capture.read()
    cv2.imshow('Frame', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am getting a problem like:

```
[ERROR:0@0.380] global cap.cpp:323 open VIDEOIO(AVFOUNDATION): raised unknown C++ exception!
```

But when if i run with  *CANYON  CNR-WCAM 920HD*, it shows nice. Where is the problem??

I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: how do you know that you are actually working with the Canyon? How did you plug them into the HUB?

Comment: Are you trying to do BOTH of these?  The Trust 720HD is a USB 2.0 camera, and it's quite likely there isn't enough USB 2.0 bandwidth to run both cameras.